# Is there a developers api for craigslist.org

Tags: api, craigslist

I am building an application and would like to automatically post to craigslist with a click of a button. Is there any way to do this?

I have an account and will pay for each post.

Comment: You should read this answer, looks like good -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633830/craigslist-automated-posting-api

Comment: @B4NZ41 That isn't a full API that will allow posting ads with an account. That only gets a feed with a query string, which craigslist already supports.

Comment: What about this -> http://support.open-realty.org/showthread.php?23764-Bulk-posting-in-Craigslist   My First comment I placed a link to another question, very similar to your, take a look there.. above the comrade place the same link.!!  ;)

Comment: We have an open discussion here about the topic http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5883/1511

Answer (score 70):

Ultimately no. You can query for listings with a search string from an RSS feed such as this:

```
http://YOURCITY.craigslist.org/search/sss?format=rss&query=SearchString
```

As far as posting, craiglist has not opened their API. However, this SO Question may shed some light and a possible solution - although not a very reliable one.

[Craigslist Automated Posting API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633830/craigslist-automated-posting-api)

Write a note to craigslist asking them to open their API,

Comment: This is no longer possible - `format=rss` is no longer supported and as of today will respond 410 GONE

Comment: Agree with @lance.dolan - craigslist RSS support seems deprecated as seen [here](https://forums.craigslist.org/?ID=309670165) and [here (notice how some links are broken)](https://www.craigslist.org/about/rss)

Answer (score 17):

Craigslist does have a "bulk posting interface" which allows for multiple posts to happen at once through HTTPS POST.  See:

http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

Answer (score 10):

Craiglist is pretty stingy with their data , they even go out of their way to block scraping.  If you use ruby [here is a gem I wrote](https://github.com/mark-nery/craigslist_scraper) to help scrape craiglist data you can search through multiple cities , calculate average price ect...

Comment: can be downoaded via the `gem` tool but currently only with this request: `gem install craigslist_scraper -v 0.0.1.alpha --pre`

Comment: Haha. Love the examples on github.

Comment: Those examples on github are pretty hilarious :)

Answer (score 9):

Good news everybody!  Craigslist has actually released a bulk posting api now!

[Enjoy](https://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface)

Comment: Note: this is USA, paid postings only, for limited categories.

Answer (score 7):

The closest I have been able to find is called [3taps](https://3taps.com/developers-overview.html). [3taps was sued by Craigslist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craigslist_Inc._v._3Taps_Inc.) with the result that "access to public data on a public website can be selectively censored by blacklisting certain viewers (i.e. competitors)", and thus states that "3taps will therefore access the very same data exclusively from public sources that retain open and equal access rights to public data".

Comment: Craigslist also threatened to Sue me for an Android app I had up for a couple months called Curb Alert! They hired Perkins and Coie and threatened something like $200,000 per scraping (capped at like $1,000,000 per day). I took my app down. Craigslist is a billion dollar company and they are hoarding the data people provide to them. They are not the company people think they are.

Comment: Craigslist is a private company who spend money to provide the public a service.  This service for most use cases is free.  I assume the OP wants to bulk sell using Craigslist.  Under this assumption the OP would profit while not contributing to Craigslist.  That is not fair to Craigslist, so to your point - "They are not the company people think they are" is not entirely fair.  Provide a person something for free then they demand more for free otherwise the original offer is somehow considered immoral.  I don't understand this philosophy.  I believe they are simply protecting their interests.

Comment: I wish one day they get shut down!