# API for posting to craigslist

Tags: api, http, rss, authorization, craigslist

I need to automate posting messages to craigslist.org through their API.

Here is an up-to-date reference for the craigslist posting API(updated on 2nd of December 2013):
http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

They have a really nice clean API, the only problem seems to be the **cl:auth** element you must provide:

```
<cl:auth username="listuser@bogus.com" password="p0stp@rty" accountID="14"/>
```

They describe accountID as:
A craigslist account number with sufficient block credit (or an invoiced account), where the username supplied is an authorized buyer for this accountID.

I can't find any pricing information or details on craigslist.org.

How do I get my account authorized for posting messages? How can I get a valid accountID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a developers api for craisglist.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353021/is-there-a-developers-api-for-craisglist-org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came into the same issue. Here's the info on how to apply for a Paid account. You have to fill out the application on the Craiglist About pages here: http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/paid_posting_accounts

Comment: Do you know if this is this required even for validating requests with the craigslist validation url: `https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/validate`?