# Issue scraping craigslist.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

I've written a spider which is having issues for one reason or another.

I'm new to scraping, but, judging by the log, it seems to be successfully loading the page? I've tested my XPath selectors in the browser and they're working fine. I've looked at the `craigslist.org/robots.txt` file, and it doesn't explicitly disallow what I'm doing.

Does anybody know what's going on?

May it have something to do with the user-agent string? Is a different version of the page being served to the spider?

**Spider**

```
import scrapy

class RentalsCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rentals"
    allowed_domains = [
        'craigslist.org'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
    }
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    def start_requests(self):
        start = 0
        nopgs = 1
        pages = []
        for i in range(0, nopgs):
            i = i * 120 + start
            pages.append('https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=' + str(i))
        for page in pages:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        prc_path = '//span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-price"]/text()'
        sqf_path = '//span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="housing"]/text()'
        loc_path = '//span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-hood"]/text()'
        prc_resp = response.xpath(prc_path).extract_first()
        sqf_resp = response.xpath(sqf_path).extract_first()
        loc_resp = response.xpath(loc_path).extract_first()
        objct = { 'prc': prc_resp }
        if sqf_resp:
            objct['sqf'] = sqf_resp
        if loc_resp:
            objct['loc'] = loc_resp
        yield objct
```

**Log**

```
(base) C:\Users\Anthony\tutorial\tutorial\spiders>scrapy runspider rentals.py -o rentals.json
0
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'rentals.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
0
2018-06-07 15:58:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-06-07 15:58:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=0> (referer: None)
2018-06-07 15:58:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-07 15:58:24 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 468,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 36594,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 22, 58, 24, 237666),
'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 22, 58, 23, 792075)}
2018-06-07 15:58:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**Output**

An empty `json` file.

**Scrapy.cfg**

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = tutorial.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = tutorial
```

**settings.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for tutorial project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'tutorial (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'tutorial.middlewares.TutorialSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'tutorial.middlewares.TutorialDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

**Log (with `yield objct)**

```
(base) C:\Users\Anthony\tutorial\tutorial\spiders>scrapy runspider rentals.py -o rentals.json
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'rentals.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-06-07 17:33:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=0> (referer: None)
2018-06-07 17:33:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=0>
{'prc': '$2400', 'sqf': '\n                    1br -\n                    895ft', 'loc': ' (North Vancouver)'}
2018-06-07 17:33:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-07 17:33:17 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: rentals.json
2018-06-07 17:33:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 468,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 37724,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 0, 33, 17, 36724),
'item_scraped_count': 1,
'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
'log_count/INFO': 8,
'response_received_count': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 8, 0, 33, 16, 533959)}
2018-06-07 17:33:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**CONCLUSION**

I finally wrote some code that outputs what I was expecting. Unfortunately, when I got it working with XPath, the script would bunch together all of the prices in one list, square footage in another list, and locations in yet another list. I prefer XPath, and I'm sure there's a way to keep XPath, yet separate each listing in a dict.

```
import scrapy

class RentalsCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rentals"
    allowed_domains = [
        'craigslist.org',
        'kajiji.ca'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
    }
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    def start_requests(self):
        start = 0
        nopgs = 1
        pages = []
        for i in range(0, nopgs):
            i = i * 120 + start
            pages.append('https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=' + str(i))
        for page in pages:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.css('ul.rows li p span.result-meta'):
            prc = li.css('span.result-price::text').extract_first()
            sqf = li.css('span.housing::text').extract_first()
            loc = li.css('result-hood::text').extract_first()
            objct = { 'prc': prc }
            if sqf:
                objct['sqf'] = sqf
            if loc:
                objct['loc'] = loc
            yield objct
```

Comment: Instead of guessing whether it downloaded the right page, look at what it downloaded. You can run in the debugger, add a `print` statement, or save it to a file to open in your text editor.

Comment: @abarnert my python is rusty af. what is the statement to save it as a file?!

Comment: Meanwhile, do you know whether the spans you're looking for actually exist in the HTML as downloaded, as opposed to being generated on the fly by JavaScript in the browser? Because if it's the latter, the only way to get that information is to either drive a browser, run a headless JS+DOM framework, or read the JS code and figure out how to reproduce what it does in your Python code.

Comment: `with open(path, 'w') as f: f.write(text)`.

Comment: One more thing: Doesn't CraigsList have a API that lets you download pages in RSS or JSON or something else easier to parse than the mess of HTML+CSS+JS designed for browser rendering?

Comment: @abarnert looking at the developer's console in Chrome, it appears one of the spans is being generated dynamically, though not the other ones. apparently there is no API [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353021/is-there-a-developers-api-for-craigslist-org#10353131)

Comment: From a quick search, I didn't find any docs on an API, and https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/apa?s=test&format=rss looks like it returns the same results as an RDF XML doc, which is nice, but the price is only available buried in a free-form text field, which… not so nice.

Comment: @abarnert refer to the SO thread that i linked in my last comment. i'm still trying to figure out how to save this page to check what exactly's being served... `with open('output.py', 'w') as file: file.write(what to put here and where in my script??)` Again, my Python is rusty af and I'm a complete n00b to Scrapy

Comment: Look at [the tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). The first example is a spider that saves every response it downloads, which shows exactly how to do it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I don't have scrapy set up, but downloading the same thing with `requests` and running the same XPath with `lxml.etree` works, so I'm guessing that _probably_ isn't your problem, although of course that doesn't actually _prove_ it isn't.

Comment: @abarnert yeah, for some reason it's returning an empty page. likely CL preventing the scrape via the user-agent string? i don't believe the issue is the XPath selectors since they work fine in the browser

Comment: It seems weird that they'd block Scrapy but wouldn't block Requests or Curl. But if you want to check that, you can [set the user-agent manually to anything you want](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent).

Comment: @abarnert i have tried `yield { 'file': response.body }` which also returns absolutely nothing, so i think issue may not be that it's returning a blank page but something else

Answer (score 2):

Is your code sample complete?  If it is, you might just be missing one line at the end of `parse`, which is to yield the item you want to add to your current scrapy job.  I forget if you have to actually yield a scrapy `Item`, but start by trying `yield objct`

i.e.

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    objct['key'] = response.xpath("/my/clever/xpath")
    ...
    yield objct
```

Comment: you don't have to yield an `Item`

Comment: hm... still no output :/

Comment: @Anthony Well, you have to do _something_ with the object. All you're doing is building up an object and then ignoring it. You can yield it back to scrapy, or log it manually, or write it to a file (as in the first example), or store it in a database, or whatever you want to do with it, but if you do nothing with it, nothing happens.

Comment: @abarnert i'm already trying to create a file from it via the anaconda terminal (i.e. `scrapy runspider rentals.py -o rentals.json`). hence why in my question i included an **"Output"** section that reads "An empty `json` file"

Comment: @Anthony That creates a file out of the things you give scrapy to output, normally with `yield`. If you never give it anything, you end up with… I think `[]`, but I can't remember for sure. Anyway, definitely nothing useful, because it doesn't have anything useful to save.

Comment: @abarnert using `yield` and doing the exact same thing in other scripts has worked fine for me so far!

Comment: @Anthony I just ran your spider `scrapy crawl rentals -o test.json` and it seems to yield at least one item ({
        "prc": "$1600",
        "sqf": "\n                    1br -\n                    690ft",
        "loc": " (Coal Harbour)"
    })  Are you sure you're getting nothing?

Comment: @Thtu 100% getting absolutely nothing. it creates the file `rentals.json` but it's completely blank, not even an `[`

Comment: Can you post your scrapy config?  and your scrapy project settings? I suspect it's an issue there.  The spider you posted is fine (though a little messy :)  )  I suspect it's an issue with your scrapy config.

Comment: @Thtu messy?! no way! how, in what way?! yes, i'll post those two things. then unfortunately i gotta go cut my hair :(

Comment: @Anthony One more thing: Are you waiting for the spider to finish running before looking at the file? If not, it could just be a buffering problem…

Comment: @abarnert yes, i am! look at the bottom of the CMD log. `... (finished)`

Comment: @Anthony copying your exact settings, and your exact spider, and what I assume is the exact layout from `scrapy startproject tutorial`, I am able to get a response.   Can you post an updated log from after you added the yield statement from `scrapy crawl rentals -o rentals.json && open rentals.json`

Comment: FWIW I think you're doing everything right as far as I can tell.  I'm just not able to reproduce the missing output part.  At this point, I suspect that your text editor showing rentals.json isn't refreshing, or some logistical issue like accidentally having 2 copies of rentals.py (e.g. if you did scrapy genspider at the top level and copied it manually to tutorial/spiders) and editing the wrong one .

Comment: I've developed the habit of closing `file.json` and reopening it every time I execute the script in order to refresh the content. I'll run the script again with the `yield` statement and add the log right now!

Comment: In the command you posted, you're saving it to `rental.json`, not `file.json`.  Did you mean `file.json` in the abstract sense of "whatever file I'm saving it to"?

Comment: Yes, `file` is just a placeholder in that context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172722/discussion-between-thtu-and-anthony).

Comment: so, i just uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled vanilla Python 2.7. However, you suggested using pipenv instead. Should I be installing pipenv BEFORE i install anything in python such as (`pypiwin32` and `scrapy`)??? thanks <3

Comment: i just got it working. if ur interested i've updated the question. id love to hear your thoughts. personally, id prefer to keep using XPaths, but instead of outputting each item as a whole it bunched together all the prices into one list, all the sq footage into another list, and all the locations into yet another list

Comment: Great glad to hear it.  Here are some usage patterns with pipenv: https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow