# craigslist bulk posing through HTML Form giving failed to parse RSS error

Tags: php, api, curl, forms, http-post

I m trying to post on Craigslist their bulk rss data posing method.

For that I'm using following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post" enctype="text/xml">
    <input name="add" type="submit" value="Create"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value='<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
             xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
             xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0">

      <channel>
        <items>
          <rdf:li rdf:resource="NYCBrokerHousingSample1"/>
          <rdf:li rdf:resource="NYCBrokerHousingSample2"/>
        </items>

        <cl:auth username="user@demo.com"
                 password="demo123"
                 accountID="0"/>
      </channel>

      <item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample1">
        <cl:category>fee</cl:category>
        <cl:area>nyc</cl:area>
        <cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea>
        <cl:neighborhood>Upper West Side</cl:neighborhood>
        <cl:housingInfo price="1450"
                        bedrooms="0"
                        sqft="600"/>
        <cl:replyEmail privacy="C">bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail>
        <cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates"
                       feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" />
        <title>Spacious Sunny Studio in Upper West Side</title>
        <description><![CDATA[
          posting body here
        ]]></description>
      </item>

      <item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample2">
        <cl:category>fee</cl:category>
        <cl:area>nyc</cl:area>
        <cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea>
        <cl:neighborhood>Chelsea</cl:neighborhood>
        <cl:housingInfo price="2175"
                        bedrooms="1"
                        sqft="850"
                        catsOK="1"/>
        <cl:mapLocation city="New York"
                        state="NY"
                        crossStreet1="23rd Street"
                        crossStreet2="9th Avenue"/>
        <cl:replyEmail privacy="C" 
                       otherContactInfo="212.555.1212">
          bulkuser@bulkposterz.net
        </cl:replyEmail>
        <cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates"
                       feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" />
        <title>1BR Charmer in Chelsea</title>
        <description><![CDATA[
          posting body goes here
        ]]></description>
        <cl:PONumber>Purchase Order 094122</cl:PONumber>
      </item>
    </rdf:RDF>' ?>'>
    </form>
```

And when i press creat button it post data to form action url

and givin following error:

> failed to parse RSS: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 3, byte 3

I want to know does I'm doing it in correct way?

if yes than help me to solve error,

if no than suggest me the other way

> here is the link to create account : https://accounts.craigslist.org/

One more thing i want to mention I tried curl way too as shown in answers of this question
[Craigslist Automated Posting API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633830/craigslist-automated-posting-api) see answer of `(krauses)`.

it showing following result in browser and not posting anything:

```
Array (
    [url] => https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.781
    [namelookup_time] => 1.438
    [connect_time] => 1.797
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] =>  ).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line should be the XML declaration.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

edit: Per http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface#submission_format

Comment: code is okay after your changes but it requires accountID which craigslist provides to premium users... they shutdown this service.... :(